# How do I do an ODBC connection to ORACLE from SSIS/ Visual studio?

Tags: oracle, ssis, connections

Despite that OLE Db and ADO.NET are newer than ODBC potentially, I've heard that ODBC connections to Oracle are potentially faster within SSIS.

So --- I'm trying to set up a simple ODBC connection to an Oracle DB in SSIS -- to no avail.

The OLDE db/ ADO.Net connections were easy. I entered the credentials and boom, connected.

ODBC proves very difficult. I'm running Windows 10 64 bit. Visual Studio 2015 (I believe the designer for SSIS was only meant to initially play with 32 bit ODBC connections). Oracle is version 12c.

So ... I did the convoluted Oracle driver install. Downloaded Oracle basic light express + ODBC. Put them in the same directory. Ran odbc.install.exe WITH admin privledges. Finally got the Oracle driver to show up in Microsft ODBC (32 or 64, ended up downloading both eventually). I test the connection in Microsoft ODBC setup? Success!! NOOOOW. .. enter Visual studio. Set up connection --- test --- FAIL! Some cryptic error .... 127 ... the "oracle" in quora32.dll can't be found.

Sigh ... It's like learning Mandarin Chinese fluently is easier than simply trying to set up an Oracle ODBC connection in SSIS. Anyone know what to do here? Are Microsoft Drivers for Oracle still available for download?

Comment: Did your try to se if you are able to connect to Oracle from both the 32 and 64 bits odbc configurarion tool in Windows?

Comment: Yes that works fine

Comment: You don't give much to work with, but it sounds to me like a 32-bit vs. 64-bit mismatch.  You may have downloaded both, but did you play with which is first in the PATH?  If your client is 32-bit but you have the 64-bit oracle odbc first in the PATH, it won't work.  And vice versa.  Remember, it's not an issue of 32-bit vs. 64-bit OS.  It's a matter of 32-bit or 64-bit client making the call to the ODBC driver.